# Eliminate Duplicates

Tags: duplicate-management

We need to start a data cleansing exercise in our Salesforce org. 
We have a large number of leads (approx 15 000) and some of those leads already have a contact in Salesforce. I would like to clean up those duplicates somehow. Do you know of an app that I can use to assist with that?

Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 ways to do this:

1.) Batch Apex, as already mentioned. Code required.

2.)Export you data using Data Loader, than find doubles using external tools like MS Excel.

3.)Create Summary report with grouping by your column. No code required. I believe this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

For easy work without code I would recommend using one of the AppExchange apps, I have worked with a free one:

[DupeCatcher](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO)

And I can recommend it, but you can search many others:

[Appexchange duplicates](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=duplicates)